# Debian No Module named numpy

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, numpy, debian

I've installed Python Numpy on Debian using...

> apt-get install python-numpy

But when run the Python shell I get the following...

```
Python 2.7.10 (default, Sep  9 2015, 20:21:51)
[GCC 4.9.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named numpy
```

When I view the contents of `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/` I noticed numpy is not list.

If I install it via pip i.e `pip install numpy` it works just fine, However, I want to use the apt-get method. What I'm I doing wrong?

Other:

> echo $PYTHONPATH /usr/local/lib/python2.7

dpkg -l python-numpy...

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                                            Version                      Architecture                 Description
+++-===============================================-============================-============================-====================================================================================================
ii  python-numpy                                    1:1.8.2-2                    amd64                        Numerical Python adds a fast array facility to the Python language
```

> Python 2.7.10

```
['', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7', '/usr/local/lib/python27.zip', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
```

which -a python...

```
/usr/local/bin/python
/usr/bin/python
```

echo $PATH

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

Comment: Please also add the the output of `which -a python` and `echo $PATH`. Note that apt is not installing into `/usr/local`, so this cannot work.

Comment: your `apt-get` is installing for `/usr/bin/python` i.e the system python, you are most likely using /usr/local/bin/python, why don't you want to use pip?

Comment: You could try `apt-get source install python-numpy` in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/` then try to change the target directory and install, you could of course just use your system python but that could lead to problems

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can tell from your `which` result, the python you are running when just typing `python` is `/usr/local/bin/python`.

It's a python you probably installed there yourself, as [Debian will never put anything in `/usr/local`](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-opersys.html#s9.1.2) by itself (except for empty directories).

How? Well, by running `pip` for instance. As a rule, you should never use `pip` outside of a [virtualenv](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/), because it will install stuff on your system that your package manager will not know about. And maybe break stuff, like what you see on your system.

So, if you run `/usr/bin/python`, it should see the numpy package you installed using your package manager.

How to fix it? Well, I would clear anything in `/usr/local` (beware, it will definitely break stuff that rely on things you installed locally). Then I would `apt-get install python-virtualenv`, and always work with a virtualenv.

```
$ virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python env
$ . env/bin/activate
(env)$ pip install numpy
(env)$ python
>>> import numpy
>>>
```

That way, packages will be installed in the `env` directory. You do all this as a regular user, not root. And your different projects can have different environments with different packages installed.

Comment: Thanks for the reply :) I don't want to use ``pip`` to instal these packages as they have to build as these instances spin up and down this all adds lot of time. Also I'm a big fan of virtualenv but we don't use it in production for many reasons.

Comment: You may backup the virtualenv and restore it to avoid recompiling. As long as you don't move it, it will work transparently. Another alternative would be to [make debian packages](https://wiki.debian.org/Python/Packaging) out of your projects, so they leverage Debian's dependency handling.