# Error "/usr/local/bin/python: No module named pip"

Tags: python, linux, pip

I installed pip, but if I try to install a package with

```
python -m pip install requests
```

it says

```
/usr/local/bin/python: No module named pip
```

How can I figure out where the problem is?

The problem is not with pip, but that the modules are not installed in the right way, so I can’t use them in Python. I am using [Ubuntu 15.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_15.04_.28Vivid_Vervet.29) (Vivid Vervet).

Comment: Is `pip` installed? You can check with `which pip`. if there is no `pip`, [start with the docs](http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/stable/installing/)

Comment: You should update the question with what version of Linux you are using; anoop's answer should work for debian/ubuntu, Fedora/Redhat/CentOS require slightly different instructions.

Comment: pip is installed and im using Ubuntu 15.04

Comment: Might sound silly, but if try to run just the pip command alone, what happens?

Comment: it shows up the options. The problem is not with pip, it is that the modules are not installed in the right way, i cant use them in python.

Comment: You installed python manually, while you should have used your distro's package management tools (apt-get/dpkg). Because of this, you have a broken installation of python. You have to fix that before you go further. Maybe start by removing what you put in `/usr/local`.

Comment: Following up: see my answer there, he had basically the same issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32679540/debian-no-module-named-numpy/32679861#32679861

Answer (score 15):

My situation is that the Python 3 works fine, but pip 3 does not work (the default Python version is Python 2.7, but it doesn't matter).

I solve this problem by the following command:

```
apt-get purge python3-pip
apt-get install -y python3-pip
```

And if you are not the root user, you may need to add `sudo` in the beginning of the command.

Answer (score 2):

My [openSUSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenSUSE) box at work did not have *pip* installed and [YaST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YaST) did not find it. I figured out that YaST was only pointing to a local package-repository which apparently was missing *pip*.

I have added the official openSUSE repository, which I found on *[Package repositories](https://en.opensuse.org/Package_repositories)* and then was able to find and install *pip*.

Answer (score 1):

Pip is a Python packaging module that helps us to install Python libraries.
To install Python libraries/modules, you need to install pip -

```
sudo apt-get install python-setuptools
sudo easy_install pip
sudo apt-get update
which pip # To check pip install or not
pip install requests
```

Comment: Successfully installed requests-2.8.0
ImportError: No module named requests

Comment: do like **pip freeze | grep requests** and check if requests is already installed or not ,also check if you are using a virtual environment.In case,if you are using virtual environmennts,you need to activate it using **source env/bin/activate**.

Answer (score 1):

I had to do something similar, and [tom's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33023599/error-usr-local-bin-python-no-module-named-pip/33023749#33023749) didn't quite work on [DigitalOcean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DigitalOcean) and [Ubuntu 14.04.05](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_14.04_LTS_.28Trusty_Tahr.29) (Trusty Tahr).

```
apt-get install python-setuptools
easy_install pip
apt-get install python3-dev
pip install --upgrade setuptools
pip install cryptography
pip install paramiko
```

Answer (score 1):

to install pip in the version you want: python3.VERSIONYOUINSTALLED -m ensurepip and then you can use with python3.VERSIONYOUINSTALLED -m pip install PACKAGEYOUWANT

Answer (score -1):

See if the package is installed in the site-packages of your Python version.

It gives the path where all your packages reside for particular Python version.

`import sys, os; print os.sep.join([sys.prefix, 'lib', 'python' + sys.version[:3], 'site-packages'])`;

If you find `requests` there, then `import requests` should work. Otherwise, add the above path to your Python interpreter's path by using the below code.

```
import sys
sys.path.append("<path>")
```

Comment: In what context is the line containing "`sys.version[:3]`" to be executed? Why is there semicolon outside the code formatting? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/33026862/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).