# Error : The program 'django-admin' is currently not installed

Tags: python, django

But it is installed, coz when I run

`python -m django --version`

it shows

`1.10.1`.

But when I try to start some project `django-admin startproject mysite` or check the version with `django-admin --version` ,  it shows

```
The program 'django-admin' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install python-django`
```

I'm using ubuntu 14.04. I'm new to django, I was just trying to follow some tutorial to learn it and faced this issue.

Comment: 1) how did you install django? and 2) care to link the tutorial you were following?

Comment: I was just started with the [django official tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial01/) and it asked me to check if django is installed. I tried the check and it was installed, actually forgot how I installed it. :(

Comment: Running `python -c 'import django; print(django.__file__)'` will tell you where your django is installed, which would be a good start to understanding your issue.

Comment: `python -c 'import django; print(django.__file__)'` shows `/home/rafaftahsin/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.pyc` @spectras

Comment: So you have some local install in your home directory. If it's not intentional, you should probably get rid of it altogether and either install it with `apt-get` or, better yet, create a [virtualenv](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/) for your project. See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32679540/debian-no-module-named-numpy/32679861#32679861) where someone had basically the same problem with numpy. Just replace "numpy" with "django" in that answer.

Comment: I think `virtualenv` is better :) ... I have no clue when and how I locally installed it ... may be it is locally installed when i run pycharm. Can it be? @spectras

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Reinstall django:

```
sudo apt-get purge python-django    
sudo pip uninstall django
sudo apt-get install python-django
sudo pip install django --upgrade
```

Also you can use [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/) and [virtualenvwrapper](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to have a better package isolation for multiple projects.

Comment: so far discussed in the comment, django is installed in local. so neither `sudo apt-get purge python-django` nor `sudo pip uninstall django` will uninstall it. will it ???

Comment: There are two ways to install django as far as I know, so one of these methods should work!

Comment: @200OK> they won't indeed. A simple `rm -rf /home/rafaftahsin/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django` will however.

Answer (score 1):

Run this command: `sudo easy_install django`
It will create a file named `django-admin` at `/usr/local/bin`
Then, you can run the following command successfully: `django-admin startproject mysite`